# Unable to implement a custom Facebook login button for IOS

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to create a custom login button for IOS 9,i have been following the Facebook's tutorial for doing so but when i button is clicked,i end up getting this error

> libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception

I have been following this Facebook tutorial,only difference is i am using dispatch_async due to some reasons.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#loginkit

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    NSMutableArray* Permissions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [Permissions addObject:@"email"];
    [Permissions addObject:@"public_profile"];

    FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:Permissions
                                   handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error) 
         { 
             NSLog(@"Process error");

         } 

         else if (result.isCancelled) 
         {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } 

         else 
         {
            NSLog(@"Logged in");
         }

     ];                
});
```

I have tried using Parse SDK's code too like so...

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];

    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) 
    {
       if (!user) 
       {
          NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
       } 

       else if (user.isNew) 
       {
          NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
       } 

       else 
       {
         NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
       }
     }];
```

But both the time,i end up getting the same error like as shown in the image below..

> [Error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfMX9.png)

Am i doing something wrong in app validation process?
Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is weird,after playing around in Xcode,i found that it is not able to get my appID and other settings from my plist even though it's there.After i programmatically set my app id using

```
[FBSDKSettings setAppID:@"appid"];

[FBSDKSettings setDisplayName:@"displayname"];
```

I was to able get rid of that error,but i am stuck at URLSchemes...i will recreate the project and try again!
Thank you!

It's working now and,i am able to get a login page,but after i get past the app login screen,i am getting a blank white screen with only a done button at th top right corner,when i click it,i get the log message that the user cancelled login.